# ErrorException Undefined index: location on create form

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add a row to my database for the objects type "Event". Whenever I press the create button on my HTML form, I get the error "Undefined index: location".

This is my save function:

```
public function save(CreateEvent $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $event = new Event();
    $event->event_name = $validated['name'];
    $event->event_description = $validated['description'];

    $event->event_location_id = $validated['location'];

    if ($validated['website'] != null) {
        $event->event_website = $validated['website'];

    }

    if ($validated['facebook'] != null) {
        $event->event_facebook = $validated['facebook'];

    }
    if ($validated['twitter'] != null) {
        $event->event_twitter = $validated['twitter'];

    }
    if ($validated['instagram'] != null) {
        $event->event_instagram = $validated['instagram'];

    }

    $starttime = strtotime($validated['starttime']);
    $event->event_start_time = date('H:i', $starttime);


    $event->event_duration = $validated['duration'];


    $event->event_day = $validated['day'];


    if ($validated['image'] != null) {
        $imageName = time().'.'.request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $event->event_image = $imageName;
        request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
    }

    $event->save();

    return redirect()->route('event.show', ['event_id' => $event->event_id]);
}
```

This is my Form Request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateEvent extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'starttime' => 'required',
            'duration' => 'required',
            'day' => 'required',
            'website' => '',
            'twitter' => '',
            'facebook' => '',
            'instagram' => '',
            'image' => '',
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return ["Invalid input"];
    }

}
```

Here is the relevant part of the HTML:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <label for="location">Location *</label>
    <select id="location">
        @foreach ($event_locations as $location)
            <option value="{{$location->location_id}}">{{$location->location_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

When I press create, I get the following error:

`ErrorException
Undefined index: location`

This is the line the error is on: `$event->event_location_id = $validated['location'];`

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your select tag is is missing `name` attribute and the value is not passing with the form. so `location` index is missing in `$request`. just add the `name` attribute in the select tag.

```
<select id="location" name="location">
    @foreach ($event_locations as $location)
        <option value="{{$location->location_id}}">{{$location->location_name}} 
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select element does not have a name.

```
<select id="location">
```

must be

```
<select name="location" id="location">
```